# PHP Cookie Not Setting via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to set a PHP cookie via AJAX. I'm putting one variable ("listingID") into the cookie name. If I hard code the name (eg. "cMapPin220") the cookie sets correctly, however I require a variable in the name to identify it.

AJAX:

```
function myFunc(listingID){

    $.ajax({

        url: 'cookie.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {listingID:listingID},
        dataType: 'html'

    }).success(function(data){

        $('.div66').html(data);

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, errMsg) {

        alert("Request failed: " + errMsg);
    });

}
```

**In "cookie.php"**

This doesn't work:

```
<?php
$cookieName = 'cMapPin' . $_POST['listingID'];
setcookie($cookieName, '1', time()+30);
?>
```

This works:

```
<?php
$cookieName =   'cMapPin220';
setcookie($cookieName, '1', time()+30);
?>
```

Comment: have you var_dump'ed `$_POST['listingID']` to make sure it is set, or is what you think it is

Comment: Is the parameter being sent up to the server correctly?

Comment: Yes to both. Even assigning the variable before the AJAX request works -->    `var listingID = '220';  ..... $.ajax({`

Comment: Aaaaaaahhhh found my issue! I was pulling the variable from an attributed that had extra spaces at the end `<div listingid="220  "></div>`  Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely in your POST data

```
data: {listingID:listingID}
```

You're not quoting the name of your parameter so it's likely pulling the value for both the name and value. Try this instead

```
data: {"listingID":listingID}
```

Comment: Problem solved. My listingID variable had extra spaces at the end. thx!